# How to plot real time charts with data stored in file

Tags: python, csv, data-visualization

Since I'm not familiar with the web development, I might use wrong terminology while trying to explain my problem. I have some machine learning apps that produce data periodically. I store the data within a file let's say data.csv . Here is an example for data.csv file:

```
1002     3.234        100
3075     2.241        65 
5540     1.1249       82
7640     1.7249       22
```

Now, I want to plot a chart based on the content of this file (The first column will be the x-axis, second column will be the y-axis for example).  and show this chart in a webpage and I want to access it with a url. ( mychardomain.com/chart1 mychardomain.com/chart2 etc) Unfortunately, this file will be modified within a time. So, I want to update the chart each time a new row added to it.

My question is for such a task, which technologies should I use ( Do I need to use web framework, web server, web socket etc ? I do not familiar with those terms but I have CS background once I got the keywords I can easily cover them). I'm planning to use python so I'd be very helpful if your suggestions would related with python.

Comment: I don't think JavaScript can read files, so I don't think you can do a static HTML page. You could use a simple django project with one view that uses python to read in the file and make the graph. That shouldn't be too difficult. ... Actually, I think there is a library called Bokeh that does all of this for you.

Comment: @HashSplat thank you for the Bokeh, I'll definitely check it out. However, I don't want to create a static file I guess. Whenever the file updated, I want to visualize this new row in the plot on browser.

Comment: @HashSplat is it possible to update plots on browser whenever corresponding file is modified with bokeh ?

Comment: You would have to use JavaScript or AJAX in some way to update the plot. JavaScript has a setInterval function which works as a timer. That's about all the help I can give. I haven't done too much with that sort of thing.